# custom launcher oncreate again, even singleTask

Tags: android

I make a custom launcher by setting below:

```
category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"
category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
```

After first launch, I tap the home key,  then Android reminds me to choose default home app. After I choose my app, then my main activity `onCreate` is called again. I set the main activity as singleTask, but it's still the same.

Any one knows the problem?